Append environment specific values to a pillar in Salt
I have a pillar file, dev.sls. Inside this file, I am including an additional pillar file, common.sls:
secrets: |
  first=value1
  second=value2

Inside dev.sls, I am including common.sls:
include:
  - common

What I am trying to achieve is to append environment specific secrets to the already existing pillar secrets (I do not want to override it). The approach I have tried is the following (following content from dev.sls):
secrets: |
  {{ salt['pillar.get']('secrets', '') }}
    dev_secret=value3

This does not work as it is giving me only the dev_secrets as the output when listing out the pillar values. I do not want to have the same common configuration inside this pillar for all my environments of course. Also, I was not able to find anything regarding this in the documentation. My question is the following - do I have to use two different pillars and then maybe to merge it into a file with a salt state, or is there a more user-friendly approach?

This question is similar to: How to join two Salt pillar files and merge data?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You need to have secrets as a structure, not a single string. Then pillar_source_merging_strategy will do all the work for you.
# common.sls
secrets:
  first: value1
  second: value2

# dev.sls
secrets:
  third: value3

# top.sls
base:
  '*':
    - common
    - dev

# salt-call pillar.get secrets
local:
  secrets:
    first: value1
    second: value2
    third: value3

